# Get all rooms for a domain from Exchange (ews) without room lists

Tags: exchangewebservices

Using this [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643730(v=exchg.150).aspx) i can get all room lists and then get all rooms for a specific room list.

Is there a way to get all rooms with ews SOAP without going through room lists? for example for some domains there are no room lists but only rooms.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No RoomLists are needed (and easy to configure) an alternative is to query Active Directory directly via LDAP/System.DirectoryService and filter based on the msExchRecipientDisplayType eg http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2007/04/webservice-to-find-room-and-equipment.html

Cheers
Glen

Comment: thanks, but this is with the EWS Managed API  and i need it to work with the EWS SOAP API.
Also, every user can do this? or do they need special permissions?

Comment: You can't do it with SOAP (EWS) without using RoomList (or the EWS Managed API for that matter), with LDAP (which has nothing to do with EWS you are querying Active Directory directly). To query Active Directory using LDAP you just need to be an authenticated user.

Comment: ok. can i do your alternative method using http request? all i have is the exchange server URL and user/pass

Comment: No LDAP is a different protocol and you would be querying the Active Directory domain controller in that instance https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx not the Exchange Server